# What do "Connection Cycle ops/ms" and "Statement Cycle ops/ms" mean in the context of a microbenchmark of a connection pool?

Tags: database-connection, connection-pooling, microbenchmark, hikaricp

I am in reference to [HikariCP microbenchmark](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

I saw two metrics that I don't really understand i.e.

- **Connection Cycle ops/ms**
- **Statement Cycle ops/ms**

Can someone please explain to me what the above metrics/measurements mean in the context of database connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a pool, we're trying to measure just the speed of pool operations -- so a "no-op" DataSource is used that does not perform actually connections or SQL.  *Connection Cycles* measures how fast a connection can be obtained from the pool and then returned.  Basically, this:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
conn.close();
```

Where `dataSource` is a HikariDataSource (pool) and `conn.close()` actually returns the Connection to the pool instead of closing the underlying DB Connection.

The *Statement Cycle* benchmark performs:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute();
statement.close();
```

Because connection pools wrap `Statement` (and it's subclasses) with proxies, and track them so that they can be closed when the Connection is closed, there is overhead associated with both tracking the `Statement` and invoking against it.  This micro-benchmark measures both.